# how to fix "FirebaseError: Type does not match the expected instance." on firebase transaction. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

on my site, when a section is deleted I want all items in that section removed so I am using a transaction

```
        const sectionRef = db
            .collection('items')
            .where('subSection', '==', sectionName);

        db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
            return transaction
                .get(sectionRef)
                .then((data) => {                   
                    data.docs.map((doc) => {                        
                        transaction.delete(doc);
                    });
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log('transaction failed', e);
                });
        });
    };
```

i am getting the following error

> (FirebaseError): Type does not match the expected instance. Did you pass a reference from a different Firestore SDK?

here is the firebase config

```
firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_APP_ID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROD_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    };
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
```

can anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the JS SDK (and the other client SDKs: iOS, Android, C++) you cannot get the docs of a collection (or of a query) in a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction).

As you will see in the doc, you need to pass a `DocumentReference` to the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get) method (of a Transaction).

You can call this `get()` method several times in the transaction, but you cannot pass a `CollectionReference` to it.

---

On the other hand, this is possible via the Admin SDKs (i.e. the **server** libraries). For example, with the Node.js one, see the [doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) for the `get()` method.

You can get more details about the difference between these SDKs, and their reasons, in this [documentation item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention).

---

So, since you use a query it means that you don't now upfront (i.e. when coding) the list of the documents to read in the Transaction. So you should use the Admin SDK, for example in a Cloud Function.

Comment: can you use the Admin SDK with react?

Comment: See my last update: you could use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that you call from your react app.